# Bootstrap Ajax Modal - Issues Showing Body and Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Im attempting to show an Ajax modal that will display database values upon submission. However, I cannot seem to get it to show the information from the url. Im relatively new to AJAX, so this could be a very simple problem.

I call the modal using this (multiple of these in a table)

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo $Name = $row['Name']; ?>">Read More</a>
```

the modal is as followed:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Member Detail</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="dash">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the AJAX

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modal = $(this);
      var dataString = recipient;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getEventDetails.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                modal.find('.ct').html(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });  
})
```

and finally the modal in the AJAX:

```
    $name = $_GET['name'];  

    //executes the SQL query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events WHERE Name = '$Name'");

    if (isset($_POST)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $Date = $row['Date'];
            $Name = $row['Name'];
            $Type = $row['Type'];
            $Region = $row['Region'];
        }
    }  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Style Sheets-->
    <link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href ="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href ="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Using Bootstrap modal</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="modal-body">             
        <?php echo $name ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what are you seeing, any error?

Comment: im expecting $name to appear or anything at all in the modal body @codehx

Comment: yeah, I understand your expectation can you see the console for any error.

Comment: @codehx I cant see any console errors unfortunately

Comment: Also what you are returning from the server page is not right. just return the fragment you need `<div class="modal-body">             
        <?php echo $name ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
`

Comment: @codehx What do you mean incorrect? Surely I will need to query the database to get the exact value that I need?

Comment: yes but you dont need the `<!Doctype.... <head>...` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it appears there is a problem making the ajax call. If we look in the inspector network tab we can see that your request to the server was canceled:

[image]

A further look into the console shows an error:

[image]

What I can see from here is that your main site is set to work over HTTPS, but the request you are making is not a secure one. Just for troubleshooting purposes try the full path to the file adding HTTPS as the protocol.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getEventDetails.php/",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('.dash').html(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

### **Follow-up**

If you look at what you are getting back from your `var_dump($_GET);` you will see that the output isn't quite right.

```
array(2) {
    ["Cardiff_Charity_Race"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["_"]=> string(13) "1431438472999" 
}
```

You can see that the key 'Cardiff_Charity_Race' is equal to '', and '_' is equal to '1431438472999'. This is not what we want. We want 'name' to be equal to 'Cardiff_Charity_Race' like:

```
array(1) {
    ["name"]=> string(0) "Cardiff Charity Race" 
}
```

To do this try properly formatting your dataString similar to this:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modal = $(this);
      var dataString = 'name=' + recipient;
      console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getEventDetails.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                modal.find('.ct').html(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });  
});
```

Comment: i've changed it to url: "/getEventDetails.php/",  which shows no errors and TEST in the console, however it is not in the modal? Think this is looking on the right lines!

Comment: Now try the $('.dash').html(data); - It is working for me with the test in the modal this way. Good job by the way.

Comment: I ran a quick GET request from console and it seemed to work. Try pasting this into your console and see what you get:   $.get('/getEventDetails.php/', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('.dash').html(data);
});

Comment: I'm a total novice when it comes to the console. Its defintley going to the AJAX call as I can call it in the console. However its not going to the server side code?     $Name = $_GET['Name'];  
    echo $Name;
which is right at the top of that file @wrxsti

Comment: Ahhh you are correct. I misread that quickly. Thought you were getting $name from the query. Try this: echo var_dump($_GET); This should output the GET array as a string so we can see if the data is being properly passed to the server.

Comment: it does seem to be picking it up - this is the result - array(2) { ["Cardiff_Charity_Race"]=> string(0) "" ["_"]=> string(13) "1431438472999" }

Comment: Please edit your question with more details instead of posting them as a comment on the answer; also, answerer: Please edit your answer with the extra code, instead of putting it in the comments. code in comments is hard to read and follow.

Comment: Technically if you break that down it is and isn't reading it properly. It shows "Cardiff_Charity_Race" ="" and "_" = "1431438472999". There is a problem in the way you are gathering the dataString.

Comment: @wrxsti is that not the correct way of getting the value?           var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
          var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
          var modal = $(this);
          var dataString = recipient;


if you output the datastring in the console it read correctly

Comment: In your ajax request try: data: 'name=' + dataString, As it currently is, you are sending the variable as Key:Cardiff_Charity_Race => Value: "".